# Como cambiar formato de fecha mm/dd/yyyy a formato dd/mm/yyyy, en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen día requiero cambiar el formato de fecha de mm/dd/yyyy a dd/mm/yyyy:

Ejemplo - La fecha actual del día me la muestra como mm/dd/yyyyy y hago la conversion con este codigo y si me la convierte al formato que yo requiero que es este dd/mm/yyyy, anexo codigo:

```
var fecha = new Date();
    var diaActual = fecha.getDate();
    var mesActual = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    var yearActual = fecha.getFullYear();
    var fechaActual = (diaActual <= 9 ? '0' + diaActual : diaActual) + '/' + (mesActual <= 9 ? '0' + mesActual : mesActual) + '/' + yearActual;
```

Ahora tengo un tabla tipo grid view que me muestra la consulta de todos mis registro, en la cual tengo campos fecha inicio y fecha final, estas fechas ya estan en base de datos, y las muestra en mi grid view con el formato mm/dd/yyyy y quiero convertirlas a dd/mm/yyyy, el tema es que hago la conversion como en el ejemplo de arriba y no me las convierte, entonces lo que hice fue tomar el mes como dia, pero tampoco funciona, anexo codigo:

```
var ArrayID = selectedId.split(" ");
    var Mes = ArrayID[0];
    var RowIndex = ArrayID[1];

var fechaInicioMes = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);
    var fechaInicioDia = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);
    var fechaInicioYear = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);

    var diaFechaInicio = fechaInicioDia.getMonth() + 1;
    var mesFechaInicio = fechaInicioMes.getDate();
    var yearFechaInicio = fechaInicioYear.getFullYear();
    var dateFechaInicio = (diaFechaInicio <= 9 ? '0' + diaFechaInicio : diaFechaInicio) + '/' + (mesFechaInicio <= 9 ? '0' + mesFechaInicio : mesFechaInicio) + '/' + yearFechaInicio;

    var fechaFinMes = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[2].innerText);
    var fechaFinDia = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[2].innerText);
    var fechaFinYear = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[2].innerText);

    var diaFechaFin = fechaFinDia.getMonth() + 1;
    var mesFechaFin = fechaFinMes.getDate();
    var yearFechaFin = fechaFinYear.getFullYear();
    var dateFechaFin = (diaFechaFin <= 9 ? '0' + diaFechaFin : diaFechaFin) + '/' + (mesFechaFin <= 9 ? '0' + mesFechaFin : mesFechaFin) + '/' + yearFechaFin;
```

Lo que requiero es que me cambie el formato al cual yo quiero, y en base a eso validar que no deje modificar las fechas al dar editar en el lapiz de modifica cuando un registro esta en curso, por ejemplo si mis fechas son del dia 08/01/2021 al 07/02/2021 que no me deje editar el registro y me muestre un mensaje, entoces mi fecha incio no debe ser mayor a La fecha actual, la validacion y mensaje que muestro es la siguiente:

```
if (dateFechaInicio >= fechaActual && fechaActual <= dateFechaFin) {
        $(function () {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Error',
                text: 'No se puede modificar la fecha de pago de pensión en curso',
                type: 'error'
            });
        });
        $.unblockUI();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: cuando hablas de grid view que usas para armarlo y mostrarlo???

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con fechas en javascript te recomiendo utilizar una librería como moment.js.
En tu caso si quieres comparar la fechas lo único de debes hacer es crear dos instancias de Date y compararlas.

```js
var f1 = new Date(2015, 11, 31); //31 de diciembre de 2015
var f2 = new Date(2014, 10, 30); //30 de noviembre de 2014
    
if(f1 > f2){
    console.log("f1 > f2");
}

if(f1 < f2){
    console.log("f1 < f2");
}
```

Para imprimir la fecha en el formato DD/MM/YYYY puedes hacer lo siguiente:

f1.toLocaleDateString() // 31/11/2015

Espero te sirva, saludos.